# Background Subtractor not working in OpenCV Python , what to do?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am learning openCV with python with reference to [this article](https://becominghuman.ai/real-time-finger-detection-1e18fea0d1d4) and I tried the same code as they have given but even the first phase of background removal is not working.

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)  # Horizontal Flip
    cv2.imshow('original', frame)

    # Background Removal
    bgSubtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(
        history=10, varThreshold=30, detectShadows=False)
    fgmask = bgSubtractor.apply(frame)

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    # The effect is to remove the noise in the background
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
    # To close the holes in the objects
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=fgmask)
    cv2.imshow('image after bitwise_fgmask', img)
    cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output for fgmask :

[image: fgmask]

output for img is same as the original frame.

what's wrong in this and what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move bgSubtractor out of the while loop. Otherwise you will be recreating it every frame:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Background Removal
bgSubtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(
    history=10, varThreshold=30, detectShadows=False)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)  # Horizontal Flip
    cv2.imshow('original', frame)


    fgmask = bgSubtractor.apply(frame)
    
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    # The effect is to remove the noise in the background
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
    # To close the holes in the objects
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

    img = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=fgmask)
    cv2.imshow('image after bitwise_fgmask', img)
    cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```